# The Scope and the life time of Session attribute in Servlet in my web application get me confused when using more than 2 tabs of the same browser

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I was doing a simple web project (you can see the code below). As far as I know, session attributes are related to one session. When I opened two tabs of the same browser and run type the URL, only one session ID is created, but two different objects of the same session attribute are running (i.e I don't want to run two quizzes at the same time. But, when I changed the question in one of the tab, it doesn't affect the session attributes of the other tab). Can you explain me why it happened like that? How can I change my code to make the session variables shared so that when I changed one of the session attributes in one of the tabs, I wanted the other tab's session variables to be affected to?

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package com.quizServlet;

import QuizApp.Quiz;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

/**
 *
 * @author Mati
 */
@WebServlet(name = "QuizServlet", urlPatterns = {"/Quiz"})
public class QuizServlet extends HttpServlet {

    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        try {
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            out.write("<font style='color:red'><b>" + ex.getMessage() + "</b></font>");
        } finally {
            out.close();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        try {
            if (request.getSession().getAttribute("QuizzObject") == null) {
                Quiz quiz = new Quiz();
                quiz.addQuestion(new int[]{1, 2, 3, 4});
                quiz.addQuestion(new int[]{1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8});
                quiz.addQuestion(new int[]{0, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25});
                request.getSession().setAttribute("QuizzObject", quiz);
            }
            if (request.getSession().getAttribute("questionsLeft") == null) {
                request.getSession().setAttribute("questionsLeft", true);
            }
                        Quiz qq = (Quiz) request.getSession().getAttribute("QuizzObject");
                        qq.reset();

            StringBuilder SB = new StringBuilder();

            SB.append("<form name='myform' method='post'>");
            SB.append("<h3>Have fun with NumberQuiz!</h3>");
            SB.append("<p><input type='submit' name='btnNext' value='Start quiz' /></p>");
            SB.append("</form>");
            out.print(SB.toString());

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            out.write("<font style='color:red'><b>" + ex.getMessage() + "</b></font>");
        } finally {
            out.close();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

        try {

            StringBuilder SB = new StringBuilder();
            String msg="";
            SB.append("<html><head></head><body>");
            Quiz qq = (Quiz) request.getSession().getAttribute("QuizzObject");
            SB.append(request.getSession().getId());
            boolean questionsLeft = (Boolean) request.getSession().getAttribute("questionsLeft");
            if (questionsLeft) {
                qq.addAttempts();
                if (request.getParameter("txtAnswer") != null) {
                    if (qq.isCorrect(Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("txtAnswer")))) {
                        qq.scoreAnswer();
                    } else {
                        msg="<p><font style='color:red'>Wrong Answer .. Try Again</font></p>";
                    }
                }
                if (qq.getCurrentQuestion() == null) {
                    request.getSession().setAttribute("questionsLeft", false);
                    SB.append("Congratulations, you have completed the quiz!");
                    SB.append("<br>Your final score is:" + qq.getScore());
                    SB.append("<br>Total attempts:" + qq.getAttempt());
                    qq.reset();
                    request.getSession().setAttribute("questionsLeft",null);
                } else {
                    SB.append("<form name='myform' method='post'>");
                    //SB.append("<h3>Have fun with NumberQuiz!</h3>");
                    SB.append("<p>Your current score is " + qq.getScore() + ".</p>");
                    SB.append("<p>Guess the next number in the sequence!</p>");
                    SB.append("<p>" + qq.getCurrentQuestion().toString().replaceAll("\\?", "<font style='color:red'><b>?</b></font>") + "</p>");
                    SB.append("<p>Your answer:<input type='text' id='txtAnswer' name='txtAnswer' value='' /></p>");
                    SB.append("<p><input type='submit' name='btnNext' value='Next' onclick='return validate()' />");
                    SB.append("<input type='Reset' name='btnStart' value='Restart!' onclick=\"document.location.href='/QuizzWeb/Quiz';return false;\" /></p>");
                    SB.append(msg);
                    SB.append("</form>");
                    SB.append("<script type='text/javascript'>function validate(){if(document.getElementById('txtAnswer').value==''){alert('You should write an answer');return false;}return true;}</script>");
                }
                SB.append("</body></html>");
                out.print(SB.toString());
            }

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            out.print("<font style='color:red'><b>" + ex.getMessage() + "</b></font>");
        } finally {
            out.close();
        }

    }

    @Override
    public String getServletInfo() {
        return "Short description";
    }
}
```

Comment: what's is in your reset method?

Answer (score 8):

I think you may have a few concepts muddled a bit, hopefully this explanation will make sense and help you sort things out.

A session lives on your application server. When created, it is communicated to your browser through use of a cookie (often named JSESSIONID). When your browser supplies that cookie to the webserver as part of a request, the server can retrieve the session and associated objects (should be serializable, see other SO questions) that had already been attached to that session (provided that this session has not expired).

As these session variables live only on the server, they are used by the server to build the response given to the client. But in order to have a response, your client needs to make a request. You made a request and changed the state of the first tab, but because the second tab didn't make a request of its own, it's state hasn't updated. (Because these tabs are in the same browser, they share a session cookie, and retrieve the same session to fufill their requests). With some more building out, you could make use of some client side technologies such as AJAX to perodically make small requests about the session state and refresh the display of your browser windows. (You could distinguish such requests by having them call a different resource, or different accept types on the request).

Now with the design of your code... I didn't look at it in too much depth, but you may want to work through your flow a bit more. It seems a GET will always reset your quiz and a post continues it? (This feels somewhat odd to me, but I can't put my finger on why... I'd recommend reading up on [REST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_State_Transfer) and designs driven from such. JAX-RS & Jersey is pretty sweet :) ).

Edit: Here's a much simpler servlet that you could use to play with. Plop it into a war, and open 2 tabs, one just to the servlet itself, and another appending the query string ?checkOnly=true. Play with refreshing each tab independently and see what happens to the count.

```
package test.servlets;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

/**
 * Counting servlet counts the number of requests to it.
 * @author Charlie Huggard-Lee
 */
@SuppressWarnings("nls")
public class CountingServlet extends HttpServlet {

/**
 * The serialVersionUID.
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 4279853716717632192L;

/**
 * {@inheritDoc}
 */
@Override
protected void doGet(final HttpServletRequest req, final HttpServletResponse resp) throws IOException {
    final HttpSession session = req.getSession();
    AtomicInteger counter = (AtomicInteger) session.getAttribute("Count");
    if (counter == null) {
        counter = new AtomicInteger();
        session.setAttribute("Count", counter);
    }

    final boolean checkOnly = Boolean.parseBoolean(req.getParameter("checkOnly"));

    final int thisCount;
    if (checkOnly) {
        thisCount = counter.get();
    } else {
        thisCount = counter.getAndIncrement() + 1;
    }

    resp.setStatus(200);
    resp.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/plain"); //$NON-NLS-1$ //$NON-NLS-2$
    resp.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8"); //$NON-NLS-1$
    final PrintWriter writer = resp.getWriter();

    if (session.isNew()) {
        writer.append("Hey new user!\n");
    } else {
        writer.append("Welcome Back!\n");
    }
    writer.append("Session ID: ");
    writer.append(session.getId());
    writer.append("\n");
    if (checkOnly) {
        writer.append("(checking) ");
    }
    writer.append("Count: ");
    writer.append(Integer.toString(thisCount));
    }
}
```

Comment: @user18651 Remember the general HTTP rule: GET is read only, POST is to create, PUT is to update.

Comment: @Gary  Thank you for the explanation. Of course, this is my first simple web project which I did it in a single day. I know I have some confusions dealing with the scope and users of sessions. I will try to understand how it works as much as possible.

Comment: The reason I make GET to reset my quiz is because, I wanted the application reset the quiz 1) when it starts and 2) when a reset button in the POST code is clicked. Otherwise, what other means can I use to detect if Reset button is clicked and reset all the attributes and variables?

It may sound a bad approach, but what I was doing is, first solve the problem, and then find the right and efficient way.

Answer (score 0):

When session is established server sends cookie to your browser. The same cookie is sent back everytime an URL matches cookie scope, which (most of the time) is defined by domain & path attributes of a cookie. So it doesn't matter if you have 2, 10 or 50 open tabs in your browser. As long as there's a match between URL you're accessing and your session cookie scope, you will get the same session. As far as browser is concerned, there is no such thing as session, so don't assume that your browser is aware of it. It just simply sends cookies. That's all.

And there are no "two different objects of the same session atribute". Session guarantees that there is only one entry for a given name. You just overwrite it everytime you do a request from other tab.

Comment: And there are no "two different objects of the same session atribute". Session guarantees that there is only one entry for a given name. You just overwrite it everytime you do a request from other tab. ........................ That is what I was expecting. As I mentioned earlier, when the score of one user (lets assume one of the tab users) is incremented, I expect the other user's(on the other tab) score also changes when we refresh it. But it didn't happen that way. That's where the confusion comes.

Comment: Is score directly connected to session or quiz object?