# Data is being shared across different tabs

Tags: servlets, jakarta-ee

I am developing a web-based java application where the user inputs some data and then the servlets return a value after processing it. It's working fine on a single tab, but on the same laptop or from two different laptops and browsers, if I open the website i.e. on two tabs then the data is being shared on the second tab as well.

To further illustrate, let's say I enter the word "hi" in chrome Tab A, and then enter the word "hello" in Safari Tab A, and then I hit the button(to pass it to servlet) at the same time on both tabs. I can see the word "hi" as well as "hello" on Safari Tab A, even though I entered this word "hi" on chrome and not on Safari, whereas the Chrome Tab returns no result as if I had sent a blank input.

I am using IntelliJ idea's Java EE application module. So far I have already tried some answers which I quite did not understand mentioned below, but I think these problems are not matching mine.

1) [Prevent shared session between tabs or same browser windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41607849/prevent-shared-session-between-tabs-or-same-browser-windows)

2) [The Scope and the life time of Session attribute in Servlet in my web application get me confused when using more than 2 tabs of the same browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6003148/the-scope-and-the-life-time-of-session-attribute-in-servlet-in-my-web-application-get-me-confused-when-using-more-than-tabs-of-the-same-browser)

my index.jsp code:

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" prefix="fn" %>
<%@ page import="Analyser.Repetition" %>

<html>
<% //GET & SET DATA FROM SERVLET
        pageContext.setAttribute("data", session.getAttribute("raw"));
 session.invalidate();
    %>

<form action="/Analyse" method="POST" id="sourceInput">
        <textarea name="message" id="msg" cols="63" rows="15" required title="Input Text"></textarea>
        <br/>
        <input type="submit" value="Analyse"/>
        <div id="error"></div>
    </form>
```

My servlet code:

```
@WebServlet(name = "Analyser", urlPatterns = {"/Analyser"})
public class Analyser extends HttpServlet {
    HttpSession session;
    private String text; // TEXT STRING
    private String[] trimmedArray;
    private List<WordsList> words;

protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        words = new ArrayList<>();

        session = request.getSession();

        text = request.getParameter("message");

        if (text.equals("") || text.isEmpty() || text.equals(",") || text.equals("?")) {
            response.sendRedirect("index.jsp");
            return;
        }
        session.setAttribute("raw", text);
response.sendRedirect("index.jsp");
    }

protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    }
}
```

each user input should be processed separately, while it's being exposed to the second tab eve from two different laptops.

Sometimes it just shares the value, and sometimes it gives the following error.

```
StandardWrapperValve[Analyser]: Servlet.service() for servlet Analyser threw exception
java.lang.NullPointerException
```

But it does not have anything to do with the entered word, as it never gives this error when accessed only from a single tab.

Comment: Your code is incomplete. But I'd guess that you are using some global state, shared between the servlet invocations. You should note that the container usually creates only one instance of the servlet, so any instance members are shared across all requests.

Comment: @SvetlinZarev I have updated the question and code of index.jsp and servlet.

Comment: I guess you are storing a session at the servlet level, you should try removing that variable of Session from servlet keep it only at the method level and execute it.

Comment: @BilboBaggins I have added `synchronized(this)` as a statement within the doPost() method (adding all statements in synchronized), and now it's not giving me such issue and is working fine on multiple tabs. However, now performance is very slow so I am not sure if this is the correct solution.

Comment: Don't use synchornize, instead remove the session  from the servlet, you will find a session associated with request, use that one. each new request executes in its own thread, if you store a state in servlet that will be shared across multiple threads(requests) which will cause you this problem, instead use request to obtain session inside that method and use it.

Comment: @BilboBaggins umm within the `doPost` method I am using `request.getSession()` to get the session from request (HttpServletRequest parameter). Could you please show this in a code snippet?

Comment: @BilboBaggins UPDATE:  So I have now edited the code such that within `doPost` method, I have altered the session statement to `HttpSession session = request.getSession();`, if this is what you meant... But now this is giving me `NullPointerException` on 2 tabs.

Comment: still stuck with the same problem, tried many techniques but didn't help.

Comment: Check for the session management code that you have implemented, it should associate a session with an incoming request, you are getting NullPointer(mostly because) you are not getting session out of you incoming request.